# Which config-file stores file associations in KDE/Plasma?

Tags: kde, plasma, file-opening

With the 15.04 release of Kubuntu, I switched from Gnome (Ubuntu) to KDE/Plasma. I did a clean install, while keeping my home directory. Now, libreoffice (mostly Calc) seems to be associated with every unknown file-type. Instead of manually fixing the associations for every file I encounter, I'd rather understand what went wrong and fix it by looking at the corresponding config file that KDE/Plasma uses. Which config-file is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Freedesktop.org “Association between MIME types and applications” specifications](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/latest/), KDE should look at these locations:

- `/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list`
- `/usr/share/applications/kde-mimeapps.list`
- `$HOME/local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` (deprecated)
- `$HOME/local/share/applications/kde-mimeapps.list` (deprecated)
- `/etc/xdg/mimeapps.list`
- `/etc/xdg/kde-mimeapps.list`
- `$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list`
- `$HOME/.config/kde-mimeapps.list`

### KDE 5

KDE well read them. It also well edits `$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list` to save customizations from File Association configuration module (ComponentChooser) or file browser (Dolphin).

However, KDE does not stores its default associations to `mimeapps.list`, but seems to use directly MimeType keys from *.desktop files.
To choose the best one, it also uses `InitialPreference` keys, provided by the applications themselves (or their package maintainer). Since this is KDE-only feature, in most cases, it is only set for KDE applications.

Configuration from *.desktop files are compiled and cached to [Sycoca](https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/Caches#KSycoca).
MimeTypes which do not have any configuration get theirs from [Shared MIME Info database](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/shared-mime-info/).

Note that *.desktop files are stored inside:

- `/usr/share/applications/`
- `/usr/local/share/applications/`
- `$HOME/.local/share/applications/`

### KDE 6

Kde 6.0 [should provide](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/plasma-desktop/-/merge_requests/2035) default applications in `/etc/xdg/kde-mimeapps.list`, deprecating `InitialPreference` system. So KDE will be consistent with other desktop environments.

Answer (score 1):

KDE stores its mimetype mappings in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`, so you might want to have a look at that file. Each line containe a mimetype followed by an `=` and the application to use, for example:

```
application/xml=kde4-kwrite.desktop
```

You can also change these associations with the `kcmshell4` tool ([see also](http://binfalse.de/2013/01/24/kde-file-type-actions/)):

```
kcmshell4 filetypes
```

Comment: This file seems to only list changes I manually did from within Dolphin, particularly it has a section `[Removed Associatsion]`, listing libreoffice several times. What from do I remove libreoffice? Why do I have to remove libreoffice from e.g. say `text/x-bibtex`?

Comment: This answer doesn't seem complete. This file does not represent all of the associations configured for me.